# Does logging output to an output file affect mongoDB performance?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB outputs to a file speficied in command line parameters when it is started.
My question is : is that log writing a blocking operation ? Does it write previous operation
to log before executing the next one ?
Will disabling logging enhance the performance of a write heavy setup in anyway ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know ... **No**, the normal "log" does not block ... it's not a log of actual operations on the database, but rather connections, errors, etc.

I'm not even aware of a way to turn this off (though you can make it less "verbose" by starting MongoDB with **[--quiet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging)**)

This is of course seperate from logging for [Journaling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling) purposese ... but again, this is designed to not have blocking issues ...

> *"Read performance should be the same. Write performance should be very good but there is some overhead over
>   the non-durable version as the journal
>   files must be written."*

I've run MongoDB with a lot of writes, and I haven't had any issues with logging. I would however suggest "rotating" your logs regularly ...

```
> db.runCommand("logRotate");
```

Comment: Thanks, I had verbose version of logging which was logging an abridged form of all queuries, will try now with quiet option. Will tell you if there is any improvement.

Comment: just curious..would VERBOSE form of loggin be a blocker in anyway ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak it shouldn't out-right **block** but under heavy load, it might up I/O use for example, therefore increasing load ... but personally I haven't run into an issue.

Comment: I don't know which kid did that, I had upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> "Will disabling logging enhance the
>   performance of a write heavy setup in
>   anyway ?"

Standard answer: measure it

Extensive logging with any backend component under heavy load can be a bottleneck - this is a known wisdom applying to every database etc.